# Can I condense these queries into less

Tags: mysql, sql, load, reduce

Is it possible to make 1 query and still pull the required data?

I have many queries and would like to consolidate them to make the page load faster.

Cheers

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where added = '$date'");
$new_items = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where isasin = 1");
$isasin = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where isasin = 0");
$notasin = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where EAN = ''");
$blank_ean = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where EAN = '-'");
$ean_line = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where EAN = 'PRERELEASE'");
$ean_prerelease = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'delete'");
$delete = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'VIDEO GAMES'");
$vgames = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'CONSOLE ACCESORIES'");
$conacc = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Games'");
$games = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Cool Stuff'");
$cool_stuff = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Unknown'");
$Unknown = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where description = ''");
$no_desc = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where product_name = ''");
$no_name = mysql_num_rows($result);
//game stats
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Xbox 360'");
$xbox360 = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Playstation 3'");
$ps3 = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Nintendo DS'");
$nds = mysql_num_rows($result);  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'Nintendo Wii'");
$wii = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where format = 'PC'");
$pc = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$total_games = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Do you need the rows, or just a count of each?

Comment: I think your last query should read 'select count(*) as num_rows from products'

Comment: Please confirm: is that MySQL?

Comment: @Adrian: the `mysql_num_rows()` suggests that.

Comment: @ypercube Of course! What was I thinking? So, I'm not THAT multitasking :)

Comment: @Adrian: You know, when I read your question, I had to search first for the [mysql] tag and then for where was that piece of info (I was sure it is about MySQL - I guess the brain had stored that somewhere previously - but I couldn't find immediately why - so it hadn't stored how it had come to that conclusion)

Answer (score 4):

You only need the counts, by the looks. Also, by the looks, it's MySQL. Here is your one query:

```
select
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where added = '$date') as Alias01,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where isasin = 1) as Alias02,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where isasin = 0) as Alias03,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where EAN = '') as Alias04,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where EAN = '-') as Alias05,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where EAN = 'PRERELEASE') as Alias06,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'delete') as Alias07,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'VIDEO GAMES') as Alias08,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'CONSOLE ACCESORIES') as Alias09,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Games') as Alias10,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Cool Stuff') as Alias11,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Unknown') as Alias12,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where description = '') as Alias13,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where product_name = '') as Alias14,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Xbox 360') as Alias15,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Playstation 3') as Alias16,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Nintendo DS') as Alias17,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'Nintendo Wii') as Alias18,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products where format = 'PC') as Alias19,
(SELECT count(*) FROM products) as Alias20
```

Each count is a column, you should alias them accordingly

Comment: You missed a few commas but you beat me for 29 seconds :)

Comment: @ypercube A few?? I missed all of them! Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the answer. Upvotes are welcome :) Just so you know, you have beaten me by seconds yourself before as well...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products where added = '$date' 
      ) AS new_items
    , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products where isasin = 1
      ) AS isasin
    , ...
      ...
    , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products 
      ) AS all_products
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the last query selects all records so the previous queries are redundant.  If you want to do this without selecting all records use something like:

```
Select * from products 
where (format='Xbox 360' OR format='PC' OR format='Playstation 3') ...
```

You can use OR for selecting *any* records matching the specified criteria1 OR criteria2.  AND is used differently and means a record must match criteria1 AND criteria2 to be returned.  Look up And/OR on w3schools for solid examples.